# apache poi and adobe poi. Are they different projects?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In our project for parsing excel files use `poi`.

I noticed that in different subprojects uses different poi.
In one part - `apache poi` and in another part - `adobe poi`.

As I understood its resolves one task - parsing excel files.

But are it absolutely independent projects  or not?

in project I see this pom.xml snippet

```
    ... 
     <!-- Apache POI lib wrapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.granite</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.adobe.granite.poi</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
   ...
```

Therefore I asked this question.

Comment: i think they are different things. adobe poi seems to be just a wrapper around apache poi

Comment: @Leo Do you understand sense of this wrapper?

Comment: probably to isolate the relevant parts of apache POI in a easier to use API :-) that's what wrappers are good for